# Get Usernames of users via Spotify API

Tags: spotify

I would like to know if it's possible to get usernames of random users via the Spotify API. If it is possible, it'd be great if someone could tell me how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs it is possible to get a certain users information using the following endpoint:

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}
```

It doesn't seem possible to get a random users information.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to get random users.